# Python: decimal module Recipe function 'moneyfmt'

Tags: python

I'm a beginner to Python and I'm having trouble understanding some of the code in the provided moneyfmt function in the Recipes section of the Python Library of the decimal module

[decimal Recipes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#recipes)

```
def moneyfmt(value, places=2, curr='', sep=',', dp='.',
         pos='', neg='-', trailneg=''):
"""Convert Decimal to a money formatted string.

places:  required number of places after the decimal point
curr:    optional currency symbol before the sign (may be blank)
sep:     optional grouping separator (comma, period, space, or blank)
dp:      decimal point indicator (comma or period)
         only specify as blank when places is zero
pos:     optional sign for positive numbers: '+', space or blank
neg:     optional sign for negative numbers: '-', '(', space or blank
trailneg:optional trailing minus indicator:  '-', ')', space or blank

>>> d = Decimal('-1234567.8901')
>>> moneyfmt(d, curr='$')
'-$1,234,567.89'
>>> moneyfmt(d, places=0, sep='.', dp='', neg='', trailneg='-')
'1.234.568-'
>>> moneyfmt(d, curr='$', neg='(', trailneg=')')
'($1,234,567.89)'
>>> moneyfmt(Decimal(123456789), sep=' ')
'123 456 789.00'
>>> moneyfmt(Decimal('-0.02'), neg='<', trailneg='>')
'<0.02>'

"""
q = Decimal(10) ** -places      # 2 places --> '0.01'
sign, digits, exp = value.quantize(q).as_tuple()
result = []
digits = list(map(str, digits))
build, next = result.append, digits.pop
if sign:
    build(trailneg)
for i in range(places):
    build(next() if digits else '0')
if places:
    build(dp)
if not digits:
    build('0')
i = 0
while digits:
    build(next())
    i += 1
    if i == 3 and digits:
        i = 0
        build(sep)
build(curr)
build(neg if sign else pos)
return ''.join(reversed(result))
```

The part I can't follow is:

```
build, next = result.append, digits.pop
if sign:
    build(trailneg)
for i in range(places):
    build(next() if digits else '0')
if places:
    build(dp)
if not digits:
    build('0')
i = 0
while digits:
    build(next())
    i += 1
    if i == 3 and digits:
        i = 0
        build(sep)
build(curr)
build(neg if sign else pos)
```

I've looked up the next() method, but I don't understand how it's implemented here.  I haven't been able to find 'build' listed as a Python method, or function anywhere.  I think it's a variable, but if it IS a variable, I really don't get how it's being used here.

Can someone walk me through the code here?

Comment: _I haven't been able to find 'build' listed as a Python method, or function anywhere. I think it's a variable, but if it IS a variable, I really don't get how it's being used here._ Yes, `build` is indeed defined in the program, look at the line `build, next = result.append, digits.pop`. _I've looked up the next() method, but I don't understand how it's implemented here._ They're not using the standard `next()` function, they've used the name for something else, which is a bad idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

basically the build and next are variables that refer to methods manipulating with the "result" variable

Example

```
x = [1, 2, 3]
add = x.append
add(4)
```

x printed should look like this: "[1, 2, 3, 4]"

same with the "next", but the next is actually "result.pop"

if you will call, for example, just "print" to python3 console, you can notice
"built-in function print", that means it is inbuild function, but that doesn't matter at all, for now, if you write your function and do the same, it will print name of that function and address in memory that contains executable function, with parentheses you say to python that you want to execute this function, back to print, if you will store the print as a variable, you can use the variable as an alias for print.

```
new_print = print
new_print('foo')
```

This is very useful when you have a function, that will call another function, this is used in many libraries such as GUI development PyQt and many others. You can do it by yourself:

```
def foo(number, function, arg):
    if number > 5:
        function(arg)
```

if you will call the foo(1, print, 'bar')
it will print "bar"

Simple enough, or still complicated?
Anything else you'd like to understand?
And happy pythoning!

Comment: Does that mean the line `build, next = result.append, digits.pop` is the same thing as:  
`build = result.append`  
`next = digits.pop`  

Also, is this replacing the built-in next() with our own next() function?

Comment: Yes it is pretty much equal, this variable assign have even its own name I think, but I can't recall it right now. In background happens some different magic in memory, but at the end of the day it is the same. And yes, you will kinda replace that default next function. In python there is conversion for calling the functions and variables that are already included in python interpreter, you add underscore after variable/function/method name: next_